# How to make a very simple user-interface program to open 2 files on click

Tags: javascript, java, c#, python, user-interface

Let's say I have 1 main folder with 2 folders, each with a file I want to open inside "New Folder", example:

[image]

I want to make a simple 2D interface, like

[image]

What is the easiest way of accomplishing that for a beginner, and put it in an executable file, so the users can easily open the two files? Would it be easy to do it with C# or Python? 
Thanks.

Comment: why not use a .bat file?

Comment: "and put it in an executable file". Well, that's not usually such a simple task with Python even if it's possibly the easiest language for everything else you want for a beginner. Perhaps look into Flask (web-based) or tkinter for your other requirements.

Comment: But can I make a simple user-interface in a .bat file?

Comment: I nominate [Squeak](http://squeak.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an .exe this will work fine.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath1);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath2);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a GUI then try this:

NOTE: you will have to add the button and then double click it and it will take you to the code behind it. Then inside the `button1_Click` method. ether what i have entered. To find the .exe right click on your project and open folder in file explorer, the .exe will be in "bin -> debug"

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath1);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Never used Windows Forms before so had to search a bit before making what I wanted.